# Compiler warning ..C language (type issue..)

Tags: c

I get this warning:

```
499: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format
```

line 499 is:

```
char query [512];
    sprintf(query, "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Netto_Acquisto),0) AS 'Totale acquisti mese' from Acquisti WHERE mid(Data_Acquisto,6,2)='%'",mese);
```

mese is declared as : `char mese[3];`
Netto_Acquisto is `char[9]`;--> in mysql is decimal(9.2)
Data_Acquisto is `char[10]`;--> in mysql is date

Sorry to bother you...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

You don't seem to be specifying the actual type of the argument at `%`, if `mese` its a string it should be `%s`.

Comment: you're right....sorry ...I did miss the s. Now the compiler doesn't complain anymore but I get a "SEGMENTATION FAULT" during execution..what do you think might be the problem?

Comment: make sure mese is ended with '\0'.

Comment: Could you please tell what I should do ? should I add \0 at the end of sprintf query ? Is that the reason why I get SEGMENTATION FAULT"? Thanks

Comment: try `%.3s` to cut it off at 3 characters (if it's not null terminated).

Comment: I tried \0 and also %3s, but to no avail.Here's the code I use in order to get mese (which is month):do { 
 printf("Insert month: (01-12) \n");
 scanf("%s'\0'", mese);
        }
        while ((atoi(mese)<1) || (atof(mese)>12) || (strlen(mese)<2));

Comment: you don't need the '\0' in your scanf. the terminating 0 is automatic. what you have adds 3 characters to the string which overflows mese. it should just be scanf("%s",mese) but even then you can overflow mese just by entering 4 characters at the prompt. advice: first use a fixed value for mese to test the sprintf. then work on your input logic.

Comment: And seems you are forgetting the escape sequences so as to print the single quotes in the query string. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you missed the format specifier as you have written it like this `%` in the code.
Just look after it you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf(query, "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(%s),0) AS \'Totale acquisti mese\' from Acquisti WHERE mid(%s,6,2)=%s",Netto_Acquisto,mese,Data_Acquisto);` you forgot to mention the escape sequences and format specifiers.